# Is there an example of angular testing with gulp, protractor, karma with coverage?

Tags: angularjs, gulp, protractor, code-coverage, karma-runner

I've seen examples using grunt with protractor coverage, but i'm using gulp and the same with karma.

How do I use protractor with karma and gulp.

Thanks.

Comment: Voted to close this as off topic. Also, I simply punched in "angular gulp protractor karma" into Google and the first match seemed like it was useful.

Comment: that's the blog post i was looking at, but it didn't work. i'll keep hacking at it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to use the following generator

https://github.com/Swiip/generator-gulp-angular